# How to use Record.update(item['id'], { :position => item['position'].to_i}) -- And not error if not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I have:

```
ListItem.update(item['id'], { :position => item['position'].to_i})
```

This can sometimes fail if there is a lot of activity resulting in the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ListItem with ID=322):
```

Is there a way to make this only update if found and keep going.. Right now the error kills everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to keep going you could wrap it in

```
begin
  #your code here, which my error out
rescue
  #code to run if encountered error, can leave blank
end
```

Or you could update the item after finding it first:

```
#mmm... I think this first line may raise an error too if not found
#item = ListItem.find(item['id']) 

item = ListItem.where(:id => item['id]).first
if item
  item.attributes({ :position => item['position'].to_i})
  item.save!
end
```